# Cross device sessions

Tags: node.js, session, express

I'm trying implementing a cross device session. i'm using a express-session plugin for sessions.

I was trying to pass the sid by parameter and used it in ids generation callback.

The problem I detected is:

1. Enter device A and set in session test=123
2. I enter device B (with sid of device B [?sid=xxxx]) and the
   session is empty (in two devices)
3. In device B set in session test=456
4. On device A see test=456

From what I can see I can only synchronize the sessions after they are started on all the devices. It seems whenever the plugin starts a session, it deletes the previous information, even if sid is equal.

**my code:**

```
// Enable session
app.use(session({
    genid: function(request) {
        // console.log(request.query);
        // console.log(request.query.sid);
        let uid = require('uid-safe').sync;
        return request.query.sid || uid(24); // use UUIDs for session IDs
    },
    store: new RedisStore({
        client: SessionRedisClient
    }),
    secret: 'test'
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
```

Comment: It would be way easier to store your session info in a server-side database and then whenever a user connects from any device and authenticates themselves, you access the session info in the database.  Then, you don't have to try to share session objects.  If you don't want to persist the info to disk, then use a data store like redis.

Comment: The problem is that I do not have (nor do I want to have a login system). I simply need the user to load a link, open the information he has already filled out.

Comment: Well, you have to share at least some user name or token from one device to the next to identify the user.  So, you can use that as a key into the database to get access to the info you want shared.  If you're putting the token in the URL as a query parameter, then just fetch the info from the database that matches that query parameter and display it.  No session is needed.